# Shift information into one column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel Sheet with information in scattered cells.

Do you know of an efficient method to reposition all cells with information so that each cell is now in the first column (order does not matter)?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480227/how-to-consolidate-data-from-multiple-excel-columns-all-into-one-column

Comment: Depending on within how many columns the information is scattered. If it's not that many, after the last column, concatenate all the columns, then cut the column and paste in column A as values. You can then delete everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there isn't too much data select all the cells, f5, press 'Special...', choose 'Blanks' then delete cells and choose to shift left.