# Move various colums into one column but leaving a blank row in between

Tags: excel, vba

Can anybody help with the following, I have various columns with different amounts of rows in each and would like all info moved to one column only.

I have found the following [How to Consolidate Data from Multiple Excel Columns All into One Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480227/how-to-consolidate-data-from-multiple-excel-columns-all-into-one-column?newreg=d07b8d91ce364df8912afd2e44b7ff91) which works perfectly, but need it to add a blank cell after each column moved.  Is this possible?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Where do you need the blank cell added?

Comment: Hi,  thanks for helping out.  I would like a blank cell added after each of the columns is moved to the first column.